# How to click the card and while clicking the next button it will redirect based on selected card?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, antd

Here in this code, two card and while clicking the card, it will be marked as selected. Click the card and while clicking the next button it will redirect based on selected card.

In this code, while clicking one card it is selected both it is one issue also. Only clicking button only its redirected to selected card's page.

Used Routing for three pages: CardSelectOptionPage, SuccessPage, FailurePage.

UI Design: Antd Desgin.

Here is code Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/select-card-moloe?file=/src/index.js

[image]

```
import { Button, Card, Col, Image, Row, Typography } from "antd";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { icons } from "../assets/icons";
import "./CardSelectOption.scss";

const CardSelectOption = () => {
   const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
   const chooseOptions = [
    {
       title: "Yes",
       description: "I need to redirect into one Page (Successfull Page)",
       icon: clicked ? icons.check : icons.EmptyBox,
    },
    {
       title: "No",
       description: "I need to redirect into another Page (UnSuccessfull Page)",
       icon: clicked ? icons.check : icons.EmptyBox,
    },
   ];
    
   return (
      <Row className="select_page_container">
        <Col xl={18} md={18} sm={24} xs={24} className="select_page_header">
           <h1>Select One Option</h1>
        </Col>
        <Row className="select_card_section">
          {chooseOptions.map((option, index) => (
          <Col xl={8} lg={8} sm={24} key={index} className="select_cards">
           <Card onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)} className="card">
            <Row className="card_body">
              <Col xl={7} lg={6} md={6} sm={24} xs={24} className="icon_part">
                  <Image src={option.icon} preview={false} />
              </Col>
              <Col xl={17} md={18} sm={24} xs={24} className="card_content">
                <Col xl={16} lg={16} md={16} className="title">
                  <Typography.Title level={4}>
                    {option.title}
                  </Typography.Title>
                </Col>
                <Col xl={22} md={22} sm={24} xs={24} className="description">
                  <Typography.Text>{option.description}</Typography.Text>
                </Col>
               </Col>
              </Row>
            </Card>
          </Col>
         ))}
        </Row>
        <Col xl={12} md={12} sm={24} xs={24} className="submit_button">
          <Button size="large" type="primary">
           Next
          </Button>
        </Col>
       </Row>
     );
    };
    
    export default CardSelectOption;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Redirect according to your clicked state**

You can navigate like this

```
const CardSelectOption = (props) => {
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
const chooseOptions = [
{
  title: "Yes",
  description: "I need to redirect into one Page (Successfull Page)",
  icon: clicked ? icons.check : icons.EmptyBox,
  link: "/success"
},
{
  title: "No",
  description: "I need to redirect into another Page (UnSuccessfull Page)",
  icon: !clicked ? icons.check : icons.EmptyBox,
  link: "/failure"
}
];

const navigate = () => {
if (clicked === true) {
  props.history.push("/Success");
} else {
  props.history.push("/Failure");
}
 };

return (
<Row className="select_page_container">
  <Col xl={12} md={12} sm={24} xs={24} className="select_page_header">
    <Typography.Title level={4}>Select One Option</Typography.Title>
  </Col>
  <Row className="select_card_section">
    {chooseOptions.map((option, index) => (
      <Col xl={8} lg={8} sm={10} key={index} className="select_cards">
        <Card onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)} className="card">
          <Row className="card_body">
            <Col xl={7} lg={6} md={6} sm={7} xs={7} className="icon_part">
              <Image src={option.icon} preview={false} />
            </Col>
            <Col xl={17} md={18} sm={17} xs={17} className="card_content">
              <Col xl={16} lg={16} md={16} className="title">
                <Typography.Title level={4}>
                  {option.title}
                </Typography.Title>
              </Col>
              <Col xl={22} md={22} sm={24} xs={24} className="description">
                <Typography.Text>{option.description}</Typography.Text>
              </Col>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    ))}
  </Row>
  <Col xl={12} md={12} sm={24} xs={24} className="submit_button">
    <Button size="large" type="primary" onClick={navigate}>
      Next
    </Button>
  </Col>
</Row>
 );
 };
```

call this function from your button!

Comment: In this code, while clicking one card it is selected both it is one issue also.

Comment: @Balaji I fixed it, here is my solution

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. Is it proper way or else is there any other way?

Comment: @Balaji nothing wrong with this method! but there may efficient ways than this. here working code sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/select-card-forked-q2hk7

Comment: what is the efficient way to achieve this issue?